# Equality involving norm on Cholesky/QR factorization

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Let $B$ be symmetric and positive definite and $B=B^{\frac{1}{2}}B^{\frac{1}{2}}$ the Cholesky factorization.

Having $A=QR$, why can we follow the last equality in the following?
$$
|| A B^{-\frac{1}{2}}||^2_2 = || RB^{-\frac{1}{2}}||^2_2 = ||RB^{-1}R^\top||_2
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any complex matrix $X$, $\|X\|_2^2=\rho(X^*X)=\|X^*X\|_2$. The last equality, $\rho(Y)=\|Y\|_2$, is valid for any normal matrix $Y$. This can be seen by using the fact that any normal matrix can be unitarily diagonalised and $\|\cdot\|_2$ is unitarily invariant.

Unrelated note: $B^{1/2}B^{1/2}$ is not the Cholesky factorisation of $B$ unless (the HPD matrix) $B$ is diagonal. $B^{1/2}$ is referred to as the square root of $B$ instead.